# I need to bruteforce a 4-digit-pin locked executable program in Linux terminal. Help? I am new to Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, terminal

I have a program called program-5.exe that takes one 4-digit argument. If it is correct, I get access and complete the challenge but otherwise it just denies access. What I think I mainly need to know is how to command Linux to input an argument. I know that 'echo' makes it give output but for this I need input. Hopefully then I can figure out how to loop it so it just brute-forces all possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following for loop from a terminal window:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0001..9999}
do
    ./program-5.exe $i
done
```

Make sure you changed to the directory containing program-5.exe first. Or adapt the location in the loop.